# In the infinity norm, if three balls intersect pairwise, their total intersection is nonempty.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, normed-spaces, geometric-topology

I am trying to prove that in $\mathbb{R}^n$ equipped with the infinity norm $d_\infty(x,y)=\max_{i=1,...,n}|x_i - y_i|$ if I have three balls $B_1$, $B_2$ and $B_3$ and point $x \in B_1 \cap B_2$ a point $y \in B_1 \cap B_3$ and $z \in B_2 \cap B_3$ then there must exist a point $p \in B_1 \cap B_2 \cap B_3$. With the standard norm this isn't the case, I can draw three balls that overlap pairwise but have no common intersection, but with this infinity norm 'balls' look like 'cubes' and I cannot. I can imagine why this must be true but I was wondering if someone could give me a formal proof, or please correct me if I'm wrong, thanks

[edited to clarify the question]

Comment: Your question is confusing in my opinion. Do you mean that you have a point $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $x\in B_1\cap B_2$, $x\in B_1\cap B_3$ and $x\in B_2\cap B_3$ and you want to show that $x\in B_1\cap B_2\cap B_3$?

Comment: Feel free to edit the question for clarity if you think it needs it, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Original question (paraphrased):** Show that if $B_1,B_2,B_3\subset\Bbb{R}^n$ are balls w.r.t. the infinity norm, then if a point lies in the intersection of each pair of balls, then it lies in the intersection of all three.

*Proof.* If a point lies in the pairwise intersection of any two balls, then it lies in all three balls, hence it lies in their intersection.

Note that this has nothing to do with $\Bbb{R}^n$, the infinity norm or balls. It is an elementary consequence of the definition of the intersection of (finitely many) sets.

---

After the question has been edited into a different question:

**New question (paraphrased):** Show that if $B_1,B_2,B_3\subset\Bbb{R}^n$ are balls w.r.t. the infinity norm, then if their pairwise intersections are nonempty, then their intersection is nonempty.

*Proof.* In the infinity norm on $\Bbb{R}^n$, for $x,y\in\Bbb{R}^n$ and $r\in\Bbb{R}_{\geq0}$, we have
$$y\in B(x,r)\qquad\Leftrightarrow\qquad \forall i:\ y_i\in B(x_i,r).$$
So it suffices to prove the claim for $n=1$. But this is obvious; if three intervals in $\Bbb{R}$ intersect pairwise, then there is a point contained in all three intervals.

Comment: Sorry I think my initial question wasn't clear, so I've edited it and hopefully this makes sense now.

Comment: It is a completely different question now.

Comment: Sorry, I know it's different now, my initial question was phrased incorrectly, but not until I saw the answe here did I realise this, I have corrected it now.

Comment: @robotsheepboy I have answered your new question as well.

Comment: Thank you and sorry again about the edit, it was a genuine mistake. This question is one of those that is obviously true, but I wanted a formal way to say it, which you've provided. I've accepted your answer.

Comment: @robotsheepboy No worries, misakes happen. Usually the first step towards solving a problem is describing the problem accurately.

Answer (score 1):

I will use the argument used in some exercise related with **Helly
theorem** (cf. Discrete and polyhedral geometry).

We consider first coordinate-orthogonal projections of the balls $B_i$.

That is, we have three intervals s.t. each pair has nonempty
intersection. Note that three intervals have nonempty intersection $x=(x_i)$ ( When $B_i =[a^i_1,b^i_1]\times [a^i_2,b^i_2]\times \cdots $, then this means $a^i_1\leq x_1\leq b^i_1$ for all $i$)
So we consider second coordinate. In the long run we have $a^i_\alpha\leq x_\alpha\leq b^i_\alpha$ for all $i,\ \alpha$.

Comment: why was this downvoted lol

Comment: I wasn't the one who downvoted this answer. That said, I'm not really sure I understand the answer provided, what happens when we consider the second coordinate? We repeat the same argument?

Comment: I think my initial question wasn't clear, so I've edited it and hopefully it makes more sense now.